# Debug in Eclipse is not working

Tags: debugging

When I try running "Debug" on my Java program in eclipse, it loads up a whole list of 'launcher drivers', with the header statement;

```
 URLClassLoader$1.run() line:not available.
```

What is going on? How can I get Eclipse debug working?

Comment: Ended up fixing it by deleting the .meta file and reopening Eclipse. It all works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up fixing it by deleting the .meta file and reopening Eclipse. It all works now